# AWS allowing access from Lambda to Postgres RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rds, network-security-groups

I am trying to get my lambda to connect to a Postgres RDS. My lambda and my postgres instance are in the same VPC and on private subnets.

On my lambda I have a security group defined that looks like this:

`Name: default-security-group
ingress: Allow all traffic from security group - default-security-group
egress: Allow all traffic on all ports out to all IPs 0.0.0.0/0`

On my RDS I have a security group defined that looks like this:

`Name: rds-security-group
ingress: All traffic on port 5432 from security group - default-security-group
egress: Allow all traffic on all ports to all Ips 0.0.0.0/0`

With the above setting, I could not connect from Lambda to my RDS instance. After a lot of playing around, only when I changed my RDS security group to allow all ports from security group default-security-group did it work.

Meaning, changed 

`ingress: All traffic on port 5432 from security group - default-security-group`

to

`ingress: All traffic on all ports from security group - default-security-group`

My question is why do I need to allow all ports in order for this work?

Comment: Have you implemented a NAT gateway?

Comment: The team responsible for provisioning the vpc has chosen to go with their own Nat gateway as opposed to the aws one. I think the answer is yes. Will need to confirm though. But why do you ask? Does the Nat gateway have anything to do with this?

Comment: When you use Lambdas within a VPC, it goes over public internet to write to the RDS instance, so you need to be able to egress to wider internet.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Does this mean that the RDS has to be publicly accessible? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: No, actually, on second thoughts that doesnt sound right. You DO access RDS by a DNS endpoint, but you can set it to private subnet only of course.